# Problem getting value from multi-dim-array

Tags: php, arrays

The following code:

```
      $options = $value[$i]['options'];
      print_r($options);
```

outputs the following result:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [field_id] => 1 
        [option_name] => I'm a normal user ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [field_id] => 1 
        [option_name] => Store owner ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [field_id] => 1 
        [option_name] => Brand owner ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 4 
        [field_id] => 1 
        [option_name] => Designer ) 
)
```

So why can't I output "I'm a normal user" using  `echo $options[0]["option_name"]` ?

My plan is to output `id` and `option_name` using a foreach loop:

```
  foreach ($options as $option)
  {
    echo "<option value='".$option["id"]."'>".$option["option_name"]."</option>";
  }
```

This should be easy.... but I'm fumbling :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second level is not an array but an object. This would be correct:

```
$options[0]->option_name
```

Comment: Ahm thanks. You get the points, since you where the first to answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using this in the foreach

```
$option->option_name;
$option->id;
```

`$options` is actually an object. Thats why you see it is an instance of `stdClass`. Each value in that class is accessed through the `->` accessor.

BTW, you can access it regularly like this:

```
$options[0]->option_name;
$options[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do keep in mind if you assign one of those values to a new variable, you're getting an object, not a string. You can fix that by doing something like this:

```
$string = (string)$options[0]->option_name;
```

This isn't an issue if you're simply outputting the way your example shows, but would matter more if you were using the value as, say, an array key. Example:

```
$array[$options[0]->id] == $array[1]; // FALSE!!
$array[(string)$options[0]->id] == $array[1] // True.
```